# Jekyll paginate blog as subdirectory

Tags: pagination, blogs, jekyll, subdirectory

I'm using Jekyll for a static site and I'm trying to generate the blog as a subdirectory/subfolder:

```
http://example.com/blog
```

In the directory structure before running jekyll, this is blog/index.html.

I tried adding pagination by adding "paginate: 5" to _config.yml, but the generated url's were of the form:

```
http://example.com/page2/
```

i.e. no "/blog".  This is fixed by:

paginate_path: /blog/page/:num

in _config.yml.

But the resulting generated pages at:

```
http://example.com/blog/page/2/
```

don't use blog/index.html as their layout.  They use the root index.html.  What's the point in even having the paginate_path option, then?

How do I get my blog at example.com/blog, with pagination, using Jekyll?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `destination` key in your _config.yml file to set the base path where you want the output to be published to. For example,

```
paginate: 5
destination: _site/blog
```

Note that assuming your site is setup to server its root (e.g. "http://example.com/") from "_site" jekyll won't produce and "index.html" page at that location. Everything that jekyll builds will be under the "blog" directory, but that sounds like what you are after.

Comment: Actually, I am using jekyll for the entire site, not just the blog. So I can't use `destination`. I ended up using [this plugin](https://github.com/MrWerewolf/jekyll-category-pagination), not to paginate categories, but to get the blog to use blog/index.html as it's layout.

Comment: For a server would you use the url of the website for destination, or stick with _site.blog?

Comment: @Mat-visual - the destination is a location on disk. So, you don't want to use a URL. I haven't tested it, but I don't think that would even work.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the same thing as user143168: a paginated first page for a blog that is located on a subdirectory (a subdomain will point to it). Jekyll is used to build the whole site. Is there a solution for this that does not involve a plugin?

Comment: @BenoitPatra, if the _config.yml file settings listed here don't work, try opening a new question with more details. (It sounds like you are using jekyll to do the full site and you want it to produce something like both example.com/index.html and example.com/blog/index.html. That's a little different than what we addressed here.)

Comment: @AlanW.Smith. Done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717458/creating-a-website-with-jekyll-that-has-a-subdirectory-for-the-blog-with-paginat thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix via this [page](http://patrick-mckinley.com/tech/jekyll-pagination.html) Basically it involves a bit of a hack to figure out if you are on the nth page of the blog and then includes a file that pulls in you blog section.

Create a file in `_includes/custom/` called `pagination`.  In that have your pagination code

```html
<!-- This loops through the paginated posts -->
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <h1><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
  <p class="author">
    <span class="date">{{ post.date }}</span>
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Pagination links -->
<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    <a href="/page{{ paginator.previous_page }}" class="previous">Previous</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="previous">Previous</span>
  {% endif %}
  <span class="page_number ">Page: {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages     }}</span>
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a href="/page{{ paginator.next_page }}" class="next">Next</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="next ">Next</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Now in your `_layout/index.html` add

```
{% if paginator.page != 1 %}
{% include custom/pagination %}
{% else %}
The original content of index
{% endif %}
```