# Creating a website with Jekyll that has a subdirectory for the blog with paginated content

Tags: pagination, jekyll, github-pages

I am creating a website with Jekyll where the main page (jekyllsiteblogpaginated.com/index.html) displays no blog content. In addition, I would like to create a subdirectory for the blog where the main page, jekyllsiteblogpaginated.com/blog/index.html, displays the post in a paginated manner.

I have pushed my example here
[http://bpatra.github.io/jekyllsiteblogpaginated](http://bpatra.github.io/jekyllsiteblogpaginated/).
The github repository can be found [here](https://github.com/bpatra/jekyllsiteblogpaginated)

You may see in the repository branches that I have tested several organisation: creating a subdirectory blog with an index.html file or to add directly the blog.html file at root level. I also tried to take benefit of the *paginate_path* option but also without success, the paginator is always empty.

This question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423665/jekyll-paginate-blog-as-subdirectory/15450560), the user says in comment that he finally used a plugin. I would like to avoid plugin because my site will be hosted on github pages.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I succeeded !

1 - Add in config.yml

```
paginate_path: "/blog/page:num"
```

2 - In you code :

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
```

and not

```
{% for post in paginated.posts %}
```

3 - A last subtle point. As seen at the bottom of the [Jekyll variables doc](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/)

> **Paginator variable availability**
>
> These are only available in index files, however they can be located
>   in a subdirectory, such as /blog/index.html.

So by renaming **blog.html** to **blog/index.html**, you finally get a working pagination for your blog.

Et voilà !

Comment: Oh thank you that was the error paginated/paginator that got me.

Comment: @david-jacquel thanks I stumbled onto this looking for a simpler replacement for my existing pagination method, and it works perfectly.